# How can I find the dimension of the standard input?

Tags: c, pipe, fstat

I have a problem finding out how big is the dimension of the stdin through a pipe. I know that a lot of you will be furious at this question, but just hear me out.

Half of it already works:

```
$ echo "BYE" | ./my_prog
```

In the linux shell outputs `4` which is exactly what I want.

The problem comes out when I try to feed it some bytes, in fact the first time works while after it doesn't work anymore.

```
$ ./create_bytes.py -n 200 | ./my_prog
$ 200
$ ./create_bytes.py -n 200 | ./my_prog
$ 0
```

and I can't understand why. I'm sure the stream is always the same length.

The code I'm using is the following

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct stat fd_s;
    if (fstat(STDIN_FILENO, &fd_s) == -1) {
        perror("fstat(fdin)");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%lld\n", fdin_stat.st_size);
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
This is the actual request:
Read a stream of lines (bytes sequence that terminates with \n) from stdin in 16 bytes blocks. Every line can't be bigger than 128 bytes.

Maybe I'm just making it more difficult than it should be?
I hope it can help
Thanks

Comment: What is the content of the generated byte buffer which fails?

Comment: Are the first and second buffer the exact same content? It would be great to have you post it within the question.

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem to me.

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: I'm not "furious" at this question, but I will tell you bluntly what you do not want to hear: your code will never work.  `fstat` will never give you a reliable `st_size` when applied to a pipe like this.

Comment: If you were to invoke `./create_bytes.py -n 100000000 | ./my_prog`, how would you expect it to work?

Comment: @SteveSummit It should print out 100000000 I guess

Comment: When you open a water tap... how much water do you expect to flow out of it? Note: you don't know where the tap is connected to; may be a bottle, may be a jug, a reservoir, the ocean, ... *A C stream (like `stdin`) works just like the water tap*

Comment: It's more like: 5 bytes flowed out of it or 100000000, no?

Comment: If you request 5 bytes and receive 5 bytes, you have absolutely no idea if that was it or if there are 9999999995 more bytes behind the tap.

Comment: yes, but I just want to know that those are 5 bytes

Comment: @ThomasPerticaroli *It should print out 100000000 I guess* No, it can't.  See the answer I just posted.

Comment: @ThomasPerticaroli *yes, but I just want to know that those are 5 bytes* If you call `fread(buf, 1, 5, STDIN_FILENO)`, and if `fread` returns 5, that tells you that there were *at least* 5 bytes available on standard input.  `fstat` has nothing to do with it.  But as pmg said, you have no way of predicting, in general, what the next call to `fread` might return.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is a pipe, it doesn't have a size. It's a stream that in principle can go on forever. The fact that the first time you ran it it gave you a number is not something you can rely on.

If you want to read everything from `stdin` into memory, you need to read data in a loop, and have a buffer that you [`realloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) when it is full and there is still more data to be read.

If you need to read in a text file and are going to process it line by line, you can consider using the POSIX function [`getline()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), or you might even read a whole file with `getdelim()` if you are sure it doesn't contain a given delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You've run into an ill-defined corner case.  POSIX specifies that `fstat` returns the `struct stat` info of a file associated with a file descriptor.  But what happens when the file descriptor does not correspond to a file it not really defined.  You might expect the stat call to return an error (and I'm sure there are some systems that do so), but on most systems it returns some information about the object the file descriptor refers to.  What info depends on the OS and the type of the object.

On Linux with a pipe (the case you seem to be using) it will always return st_size = 0 (which implies you are using something other than Linux).  I would imagine there are systems that return with st_size set to the amount of data buffered in the pipe, as that seems a useful piece of information.  Your results seem consistent with that.

Comment: *You've run into an ill-defined corner case.*  I wouldn't call it a corner case - it's more like asking "What does the number `5` smell like?"  It's just not applicable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's in keeping with "it should return an error".  The fact that it doesn't in the POSIX spec is what is ill-defined.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment I asked

> If you were to invoke `./create_bytes.py -n 100000000 | ./my_prog`, how would you expect it to work?

and you replied

> It should print out 100000000 I guess

So let's think about this, and ask: *How could this possibly work?*

The `create_bytes.py` script is going to write 100,000,000 bytes.  Where do they go?  Into the pipe.

But what happens over in `my_prog`?  It doesn't actually read any characters from the pipe, it just asks, what is the "size" of the pipe?

But if `create_bytes.py` has written 100,000,000 characters, and if `my_prog` hasn't read them, where are they?  Are they all "in the pipe"?  And the answer is, no, they are not.

Pipes have a finite capacity.  If they fill up, and if the reader doesn't read characters out fast enough, the operating system automatically puts the writing process to sleep.  The writing process isn't woken up again, isn't given the opportunity to write any more characters, until some empty space has cleared up in the pipe for it to write into again.

My point is that if pipes have a finite capacity (as I assert that they do), it's impossible for the example I posed to print "100000000", for the simple reason that there is no piece of code, anywhere, that can possibly read and count those characters.

You might imagine that `fstat` ought to read and count them in this situation somehow, but (a) it doesn't and (b) it *couldn't*.  If `fstat` read characters from the pipe so it could count them, the characters would be gone.  If your program then tried to read them (perhaps down below the `...` you had in your code fragment), it wouldn't be able to read them, and that would be Wrong.

But, to convince yourself, I encourage you to try that invocation

```
./create_bytes.py -n 100000000 | ./my_prog
```

and see what you get.  I'll bet you $100 you don't get "100000000", but the result you do get might be interesting.

I don't have your `create_bytes.py` script, so instead I tried

```
yes | a.out
```

[`yes`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) is a standard Unix program that prints "y" an infinite number of times.  `a.out` was where I'd just compiled your test program, after fixing it up a bit.  And, on my machine, it printed

```
65536
```

So evidently, on my machine, when `fstat` is called on a file descriptor that's connected to a pipe, `fstat` fills in `st_size` with the size of the contents of the pipe, and on my machine, pipes evidently have a capacity of 65536, which is of course 2<sup>16</sup>.